# SQL Fast counting of deep quantity (relationship one to many 2x)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

There are 3 sqlalchemy tables.

**Gardeners** (a gardener can have many trees):

```
class Gardener(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'gardeners'

    gardener_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(15))
    apple_trees = relationship('AppleTrees', backref='gardener_trees')
```

```
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| gardener_id      | int          | Yes  | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name             | varchar(15)  | Yes  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

+------------------+--------------+
| gardener_id      | name         |
+------------------+--------------+
| 1                | Steve        |
| 2                | Ronald       |
+------------------+--------------+
```

**Trees** belong to different gardeners (there can be many apples on the tree)

```
class AppleTrees(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'trees'

    tree_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    gard_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('gardeners.gardener_id'))
    apples = relationship('Apples', backref='tree_apples')
```

```
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| tree_id          | int          | Yes  | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| gard_id          | int          | Yes  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

+------------------+--------------+
| tree_id          | gard_id      |
+------------------+--------------+
| 1                | 1            |
| 2                | 2            |
| 3                | 2            |
+------------------+--------------+
```

**Apples** belong to different trees

```
class Apples(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'apples'
    apple_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    ap_tree_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('trees.tree_id'))
```

```
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| apple_id         | int          | Yes  | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ap_tree_id       | int          | Yes  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

+------------------+--------------+
| apple_id         | ap_tree_id   |
+------------------+--------------+
| 1                | 1            |
| 2                | 2            |
| 3                | 3            |
| 4                | 1            |
| 5                | 3            |
+------------------+--------------+
/* As you can see, Steve has 2 apples */
```

And this is a dilemma how it is **reasonable** to find out the number of apples of a particular gardener.

Wrote this:

```
gardener = session.query(Gardener).filter_by(name='Steve').first()
apple_counter = 0
for tree in gardener.apple_trees:
    for apple in tree.apples:
        apple_counter += 1
```

But I am 100% sure that this is a very bad and slow technique.

A huge request to help. I would really like to see and understand how this problem is being solved by working with sqlalchemy objects and | or an ordinary SQL request. I apologize in advance for stupidity and thank you very much for any of your decisions and tips!

Comment: To discuss SQL, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and any SELECTs that were generated.

Comment: Rick James, corrected, thanks for the remark.

Comment: That "for" loop can probably be eliminated via SQL that involves a `COUNT(*)`.  Please show us the `SELECT` that it generated.

Comment: In the way you have your tables, one tree can only belong to one gardener (because tree_id is PK, it cannot be two times the same tree_id), and apples belong only to one tree (because the same reason, apple_id is PK)